# Save a single worksheet as CSV/xlsx file error 1004 (but does work when use 'export as fixed format' for PDF)

Tags: vba, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I have managed to get this to save as a PDF using 'ExportAsFixedFormat', but when I try to use 'SaveAs' to get a CSV (although I would accept xlsx too!) I get:

> Run time error: 1004 Application defined or Object defined error

I have spent way to long trying to do this and can't find any answers that work for me online...

```
Sub SaveTrackingSheet()


   Dim NewPathTrack As String
   NewPathTrack = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF Outputs\" & Range("NameTrack").Text & "\"
   If Dir(NewPathTrack, 63) = "" Then MkDir NewPathTrack

   Dim NewPathDealer As String
   NewPathDealer = NewPathTrack & Range("CodeTrack").Text & " - " & Range("NameTrack").Text & "\"
   If Dir(NewPathDealer, 63) = "" Then MkDir NewPathDealer


   Sheets("Tracking Sheet").SaveAs _
    Filename:=NewPathDealer & "\" & Range("CodeTrack").Text & " - Tracking Sheet" & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    ConflictResolution:=2, _
    Local:=True, _
    CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

This is the line that errors:

```
   Sheets("Tracking Sheet").SaveAs _
    Filename:=NewPathDealer & "\" & Range("DealerCodeTrack").Text & " - Tracking Sheet" & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    ConflictResolution:=2, _
    Local:=True, _
    CreateBackup:=False
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of `Filename` when it errors?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to save a workbook not a worksheet? e.g. change `Sheets("Tracking Sheet")` to `ThisWorkbook` and it works fine...

Comment: @jamheadart I only want to save one sheet (not the whole workbook). I tried to create a copy of the sheet then used 'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs' instead but still an 1004 error. Although the error changed to 'file could not be accessed' within 1004

Comment: I've had it where using a symbolic reference to fileformat constants has failed. Try replacing FileFormat:=xlCSV, with FileFormat:=6,

Comment: @Paula when I used `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs' with the CSV file extension you had, it only saved the active sheet as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileformat:=xlCSVMSDOS
```

Check fileformat specifications at https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlfileformat-enumeration-excel

**UPDATED RIGHT NOW:**

The code that works for me is:

```
Sub SaveTrackingSheet()

Dim NewPathTrack As String
   NewPathTrack = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDF Outputs\" & Range("NameTrack").Text & "\"
   If Dir(NewPathTrack, 63) = "" Then MkDir NewPathTrack

   Dim NewPathDealer As String
   NewPathDealer = NewPathTrack & Range("CodeTrack").Text & " - " & Range("NameTrack").Text & "\"
   If Dir(NewPathDealer, 63) = "" Then MkDir NewPathDealer


   Sheets("Tracking Sheet").SaveAs _
    Filename:=NewPathDealer & Range("CodeTrack").Text & " - Tracking Sheet" & ".csv", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    Local:=True, _
    CreateBackup:=False

    'ConflictResolution:=2 This line causes the error

End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe the values of Range("CodeTrack").Text  or Range("NameTrack").Text have characters not allowed in filenames or carpetnames? Like / or ¿

Comment: Found it. You used twice the symbol / just Type  Filename:=NewPathDealer & Range("CodeTrack").Value & " - Tracking Sheet" & ".csv"  I deleted the & "/" & because that made the url like "carpetname//filename".

Comment: Also, the line ` 'ConflictResolution:=2` causes trouble. I deleted it and the macro worked for me.

Comment: They don't unfortunately,  CodeTrack e.g. 565736VA. CodeName e.g. Red(colour)

Comment: Thank you!!! turned out that by using .Value as you have above rather than .text worked!!